# compress output tiff with g4 compression

Tags: c++, opencv, graphicsmagick, libtiff

How to write a file as `tiff` with g4 compression??

```
imwrite(string("compressed.tif"), res);
```

## update

## image processing

This is the processing of the image data before the data is sent to `write_fax()` so further processing should not be necessary (have commented out the processing in `write_fax`).. But the output file is completely black..

```
res.convertTo(res, CV_32FC1, 1.0 / 255.0);
res = 1.0 - res;
res = Img + res;
threshold(res, res, 0.85, 1, THRESH_BINARY);
// sends data to `write_fax()`
```

## complete code

```
/*
 *  Compile
 *  # g++ txtbin.cpp -o txtbin -ltiff `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`
 *
 *  Run
 *  # ./txtbin input.jpg output.png
 */

#include "string"
#include "fstream"
#include "/usr/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "/usr/include/boost/tuple/tuple.hpp"

#include "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/tiff.h"
#include "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/tiffio.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace boost;

void CalcBlockMeanVariance(Mat& Img, Mat& Res, float blockSide=21, float contrast=0.01){
    /*
     *  blockSide: set greater for larger fonts in image
     *  contrast: set smaller for lower contrast image
     */

    Mat I;
    Img.convertTo(I, CV_32FC1);
    Res = Mat::zeros(Img.rows / blockSide, Img.cols / blockSide, CV_32FC1);
    Mat inpaintmask;
    Mat patch;
    Mat smallImg;
    Scalar m, s;

    for(int i = 0; i < Img.rows - blockSide; i += blockSide){
        for(int j = 0; j < Img.cols - blockSide; j += blockSide){
            patch = I(Range(i, i + blockSide + 1), Range(j, j + blockSide + 1));
            meanStdDev(patch, m, s);

            if(s[0] > contrast){
                Res.at<float>(i / blockSide, j / blockSide) = m[0];
            }
            else{
                Res.at<float>(i / blockSide, j / blockSide) = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    resize(I, smallImg, Res.size());

    threshold(Res, inpaintmask, 0.02, 1.0, THRESH_BINARY);

    Mat inpainted;
    smallImg.convertTo(smallImg, CV_8UC1, 255);

    inpaintmask.convertTo(inpaintmask, CV_8UC1);
    inpaint(smallImg, inpaintmask, inpainted, 5, INPAINT_TELEA);

    resize(inpainted, Res, Img.size());
    Res.convertTo(Res, CV_32FC1, 1.0 / 255.0);
}

tuple<int, int, int, int> detect_text_box(string input, Mat& res, bool draw_contours=false){
    Mat large = imread(input);

    bool test_output = false;

    int
        top = large.rows,
        bottom = 0,
        left = large.cols,
        right = 0;

    int
        rect_bottom,
        rect_right;

    Mat rgb;
    // downsample and use it for processing
    pyrDown(large, rgb);
    Mat small;
    cvtColor(rgb, small, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    // morphological gradient
    Mat grad;
    Mat morphKernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3, 3));
    morphologyEx(small, grad, MORPH_GRADIENT, morphKernel);
    // binarize
    Mat bw;
    threshold(grad, bw, 0.0, 255.0, THRESH_BINARY | THRESH_OTSU);
    // connect horizontally oriented regions
    Mat connected;
    morphKernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(9, 1));
    morphologyEx(bw, connected, MORPH_CLOSE, morphKernel);
    // find contours
    Mat mask = Mat::zeros(bw.size(), CV_8UC1);
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    findContours(connected, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
    // filter contours
    for(int idx = 0; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0]){
        Rect rect = boundingRect(contours[idx]);
        Mat maskROI(mask, rect);
        maskROI = Scalar(0, 0, 0);
        // fill the contour
        drawContours(mask, contours, idx, Scalar(255, 255, 255), CV_FILLED);
        // ratio of non-zero pixels in the filled region
        double r = (double)countNonZero(maskROI) / (rect.width * rect.height);

        // assume at least 45% of the area is filled if it contains text
        if (r > 0.45 && 
        (rect.height > 8 && rect.width > 8) // constraints on region size
        // these two conditions alone are not very robust. better to use something 
        //like the number of significant peaks in a horizontal projection as a third condition
        ){
            if(draw_contours){
                rectangle(res, Rect(rect.x * 2, rect.y * 2, rect.width * 2, rect.height * 2), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
            }

            if(test_output){
                rectangle(rgb, rect, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
            }

            if(rect.y < top){
                top = rect.y;
            }
            rect_bottom = rect.y + rect.height;
            if(rect_bottom > bottom){
                bottom = rect_bottom;
            }
            if(rect.x < left){
                left = rect.x;
            }
            rect_right = rect.x + rect.width;
            if(rect_right > right){
                right = rect_right;
            }
        }
    }

    if(draw_contours){
        rectangle(res, Point(left * 2, top * 2), Point(right * 2, bottom * 2), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
    }

    if(test_output){
        rectangle(rgb, Point(left, top), Point(right, bottom), Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
        imwrite(string("test_text_contours.jpg"), rgb);
    }

    return make_tuple(left * 2, top * 2, (right - left) * 2, (bottom - top) * 2);
}

// just tiny exception generator
void except(bool condition, const std::string &message = "")
{
    if (!condition)
        throw std::runtime_error("Error: " + message);
}

bool write_fax(
    const std::string &name, const cv::Mat &src, uint8_t threshold = 150)
{
    cv::Mat image;
    /*if (src.channels() == 3)
        cv::cvtColor(src, image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    else if (src.channels() == 4)
        cv::cvtColor(src, image, CV_BGRA2GRAY);
    else*/
        src.copyTo(image);

    //assert(image.depth() == CV_8U && "working only with 8-bit images now");

    int width = image.cols;
    int height = image.rows;

    // do NOT put "wb" as the mode, because the b means "big endian" mode, not "binary" mode.
    // http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/man/TIFFOpen.3tiff.html
    TIFF* pTiffHandle = TIFFOpen(name.c_str(), "w");
    if (!pTiffHandle)
    {
        printf("can't open TIFF descriptor\n");
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, width), "width");
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, height), "length");
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, 1), "bits per sample");
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1), "samples per pixel");
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_ROWSPERSTRIP, 1), "rows per strip");

    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_COMPRESSION, COMPRESSION_CCITTFAX4), "compression");
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC, PHOTOMETRIC_MINISWHITE), "photometric");
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_FILLORDER, FILLORDER_MSB2LSB), "photometric");
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG, PLANARCONFIG_CONTIG), "planar config");
    //except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_PREDICTOR, predictor), "predictor");
    //except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_STRIPOFFSETS, strip_offsets), "strip offsets");

    // not necessary
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION, 200.0), "res x");
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION, 200.0), "res y");
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT, RESUNIT_INCH), "res unit");

    std::vector<uchar> _buffer(width / 8 + 8, 0);
    uchar* buffer = &_buffer[0];
    int bytes = int(width / 8.0 + 0.5);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        uint8_t *src_row = image.ptr(y);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x, ++src_row)
        {
            uint8_t eight_pixels = buffer[x / 8];
            eight_pixels = eight_pixels << 1;
            if (*src_row < threshold)
                eight_pixels = eight_pixels | 1;  //
            buffer[x / 8] = eight_pixels;
        }

        // for the some reason writeEncodedStrip doesn't work
//      except(TIFFWriteEncodedStrip(pTiffHandle, y, buffer, bytes) != -1, "write scanline");
        except(TIFFWriteScanline(pTiffHandle, buffer, y,  bytes) != -1, "write scanline");
    }

    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error &e)
    {
        printf("TIFF writing: %s\n", e.what());
        TIFFClose(pTiffHandle);
        return false;
    }

    TIFFClose(pTiffHandle);
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    string input;
    string output = "output.png";

    int
        width = 0,
        height = 0;

    bool
        crop = false,
        draw = false;

    float margin = 0;

    //  Return error if arguments are missing
    if(argc < 3){
        cerr << "\nUsage: txtbin input [options] output\n\n"
            "Options:\n"
            "\t-w <number>          -- set max width (keeps aspect ratio)\n"
            "\t-h <number>          -- set max height (keeps aspect ratio)\n"
            "\t-c                   -- crop text content contour\n"
            "\t-m <number>          -- add margins (number in %)\n"
            "\t-d                   -- draw text content contours (debugging)\n" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    //  Parse arguments
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++){
        if(i == 1){
            input = string(argv[i]);

            //  Return error if input file is invalid
            ifstream stream(input.c_str());
            if(!stream.good()){
                cerr << "Error: Input file is invalid!" << endl;
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else if(string(argv[i]) == "-w"){
            width = atoi(argv[++i]);
        }
        else if(string(argv[i]) == "-h"){
            height = atoi(argv[++i]);
        }
        else if(string(argv[i]) == "-c"){
            crop = true;
        }
        else if(string(argv[i]) == "-m"){
            margin = atoi(argv[++i]);
        }
        else if(string(argv[i]) == "-d"){
            draw = true;
        }
        else if(i == argc - 1){
            output = string(argv[i]);
        }
    }

    Mat Img = imread(input, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat res;
    Img.convertTo(Img, CV_32FC1, 1.0 / 255.0);
    CalcBlockMeanVariance(Img, res);
    res = 1.0 - res;
    res = Img + res;
    threshold(res, res, 0.85, 1, THRESH_BINARY);

    int
        txt_x,
        txt_y,
        txt_width,
        txt_height;

    if(crop || draw){
        tie(txt_x, txt_y, txt_width, txt_height) = detect_text_box(input, res, draw);
    }

    if(crop){
        res = res(Rect(txt_x, txt_y, txt_width, txt_height));
    }

    if(margin){
        int border = res.cols * margin / 100;
        copyMakeBorder(res, res, border, border, border, border, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar(255, 255, 255));
    }

    float
        width_input = res.cols,
        height_input = res.rows;

    bool resized = false;

    //  Downscale image
    if(width > 0 && width_input > width){
        float scale = width_input / width;
        width_input /= scale;
        height_input /= scale;
        resized = true;
    }
    if(height > 0 && height_input > height){
        float scale = height_input / height;
        width_input /= scale;
        height_input /= scale;
        resized = true;
    }
    if(resized){
        resize(res, res, Size(round(width_input), round(height_input)));
    }

    //imwrite(output, res * 255);
    write_fax(output+".tif", res * 255);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no OpenCV support for that. You may want to use libtiff directly.

Comment: @miki, could you provide an example where you don't have to write the file to disk before compression with libtiff? Started with c++ this week so I'm not that familiar with it yet :)

Comment: No idea, sorry. I never used it directly. But **why** you need exactly TIFF with G4 compression?

Comment: I need to binarize scanned documents.. It has to be 1bit monochrome. TIFF with g4 compression give the best reduction in file size

Comment: Well, in your position I'd use PNG (which is better supported in OpenCV with some compression options you can play with). Or if disk space is an issue, you can save the binary raw data. For libtiff stuff, good luck!

Comment: @miki, Have tried a couple of things with png, but tiff is by far the best solution if you want to reduce the filesize

Comment: What is the objection to intermediate files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple *C++* function for writing g4 **TIFFS** with libtiff:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include <tiff.h>
#include <tiffio.h>

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>

// just tiny exception generator
void except(bool condition, const std::string &message = "")
{
    if (!condition)
        throw std::runtime_error("Error: " + message);
}

bool write_fax(
    const std::string &name, const cv::Mat &src, uint8_t threshold = 150)
{
    cv::Mat image;
    if (src.channels() == 3)
        cv::cvtColor(src, image, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    else if (src.channels() == 4)
        cv::cvtColor(src, image, CV_BGRA2GRAY);
    else
        src.copyTo(image);

    if (image.depth() != CV_8U)
    {
        cv::Mat tmp;
        image.convertTo(tmp, CV_8U);
        std::swap(image, tmp);
    }

    int width = image.cols;
    int height = image.rows;

    // do NOT put "wb" as the mode, because the b means "big endian" mode, not "binary" mode.
    // http://www.remotesensing.org/libtiff/man/TIFFOpen.3tiff.html
    TIFF* pTiffHandle = TIFFOpen(name.c_str(), "w");
    if (!pTiffHandle)
    {
        printf("can't open TIFF descriptor\n");
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, width), "width");
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, height), "length");
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_BITSPERSAMPLE, 1), "bits per sample");
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_SAMPLESPERPIXEL, 1), "samples per pixel");
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_ROWSPERSTRIP, 1), "rows per strip");

    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_COMPRESSION, COMPRESSION_CCITTFAX4), "compression");
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_PHOTOMETRIC, PHOTOMETRIC_MINISWHITE), "photometric");
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_FILLORDER, FILLORDER_MSB2LSB), "photometric");
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_PLANARCONFIG, PLANARCONFIG_CONTIG), "planar config");
    //except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_PREDICTOR, predictor), "predictor");
    //except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_STRIPOFFSETS, strip_offsets), "strip offsets");

    // not necessary
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION, 200.0), "res x");
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION, 200.0), "res y");
    except(TIFFSetField(pTiffHandle, TIFFTAG_RESOLUTIONUNIT, RESUNIT_INCH), "res unit");

    std::vector<uchar> _buffer(width / 8 + 8, 0);
    uchar* buffer = &_buffer[0];
    int bytes = int(width / 8.0 + 0.5);
    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        uint8_t *src_row = image.ptr(y);
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x, ++src_row)
        {
            uint8_t eight_pixels = buffer[x / 8];
            eight_pixels = eight_pixels << 1;
            if (*src_row < threshold)
                eight_pixels = eight_pixels | 1;  //
            buffer[x / 8] = eight_pixels;
        }

        // for the some reason writeEncodedStrip doesn't work
//      except(TIFFWriteEncodedStrip(pTiffHandle, y, buffer, bytes) != -1, "write scanline");
        except(TIFFWriteScanline(pTiffHandle, buffer, y,  bytes) != -1, "write scanline");
    }

    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error &e)
    {
        printf("TIFF writing: %s\n", e.what());
        TIFFClose(pTiffHandle);
        return false;
    }

    TIFFClose(pTiffHandle);
    return true;
}
```

Threshold is value for consider color as black of white (because g4 uses only one bit for color).

Compilation command in linux:

```
g++ <source name> -o <output name> `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` -ltiff
```

Code is self-commented, hope there is no unclear places.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but there is som compile errors.. Have updated my question.. (sorry I'm new to C) :)

Comment: @clarkk: ok, updated code with all necessary includes. Also I provided sample compilation string

Comment: Have not got it to work.. But get the error: `txtbin_tif: txtbin-04.cpp:175: bool write_fax(const string&, const cv::Mat&, uint8_t): Assertion `image.depth() == 0 && "working only with 8-bit images now"' failed.
Aborted` But the file is already at least greyscale.. Have added the complete code to my quesiton

Comment: @clarkk: it accepts 8-bit images. You pass 32-bit float image, and, of course, get a error... OK, I made one more fix: instead assert I convert image.